# PHP how to loop throw numbers and get alphbets?

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

I want to define the start of alphabet and loop throw a counter and get the alphabet after start point.
I used the bellow loop to do that, but how I can increment the start point by 3 character.

```
$start = 'G';
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $col = $start;
    $start++;
}
```

The output of above loop is all the consecutive alphabet character after G up to 10th, but what i want to take is `G,J,M,...` and so on. SO it means i should take the `3rd` character after the current character, so how I can do that without using array of alphabets? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

Use `range()` and make your code simpler..

```
<?php
$alph = range('G','Z',3); //<=-- 3 is the step increment.
print_r($alph);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => G
    [1] => J
    [2] => M
    [3] => P
    [4] => S
    [5] => V
    [6] => Y
)
```

Comment: Good answer!  I didn't know that function existed  :)

Comment: but i want to not define the end point of range because i want to use with phpexcel

Comment: If you want to use it with PHPExcel, why don't you use PHPExcel's built in functions for converting numbers to Excel column names, such as `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` instead

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, Members on SO who upvote for competing answers are really rare. I appreciate your sportsmanship. Thanks!